# Monte carlo integration for area under curve

Tags: c++, montecarlo

I have managed to code a program that uses the monte-carlo method to estimate pi. Now i am trying to instead estimate the area of plane curves, specifically a quadrifolium.[See image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfrdc.png)
I have been unable to do this so far. Surely this only involves a tweak to my current code? Any help or advice would be appreciated. Here is what i already have:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <xmemory>
using namespace std;
double pi_(double accuracy)
{
int n = 0, d = 0;
double x, y, latest_pi = 0;
double Origin_dist = 0;
do
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    x = rand() % 100;
    y = rand() % 100;
    Origin_dist = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    if (Origin_dist < 100.0)
    {
        d++;
        n++;
    }
    else
    {
        n++;
    }
    latest_pi = 4.0 * (d + 1.0) / (n + 1.0);
} while ((d < 3100) || (4.0 / (n + 1.0) < accuracy));
return latest_pi;
}
int main()
{
double accuracy;
srand((int)time(0));
cout << "Enter the accuracy: \n";
cin >> accuracy;
cout << pi_(accuracy) << endl;
```

Comment: You gave an image, but your code use distance to estimate if a point belongs to the disc. Do you have an equation that would allow to determinate if a point is in your quadrifolium?

Comment: Sorry I do not and it has not been provided with the problem. I only have the equation of the quadrifolium. ((x^2 + y^2)^3) = 4 * x^2 * y^2. I have managed to code a program to estimate the natural logarithm of numbers too. I cannot figure this out though.

Comment: This is already something. Since your surface is centered, a way to solve your problem might be to find for each point the intersection between the line formed by this point and the origin and the part of the curve located in the same quarter of the plane. If you find that the distance between the origin and this intersection is superior to the distance between the point and the origin, then the point belongs to the surface. If not, or if you simply can’t find the intersection, then it does not belong to the surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I must precise that Monte Carlo is by far not the best method to solve this problem. This solution exploit the fact that for both x and y superior to 0, ((x^2+y^2)^3 < 4*x^2*y^2) => (x,y) belongs to the surface.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

double pow(double x, int n){
    double r=1.0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        r=r*x;
        }
    return x;
    }

bool belongTo_quadrifolium(double x, double y){
    return pow(pow(x,2) + pow(y,2), 3) - 4 * (pow(x, 2) * pow(y, 2)) < 0; 
    }



double montecarlo(double accuracy){
    unsigned int n = 0, d = 0;
    double x, y;
    do
    {
        x = 1.0*rand() / (RAND_MAX-1);
        y = 1.0*rand() / (RAND_MAX-1);
        if (belongTo_quadrifolium(x, y)){
            d++;
            n++;
            }
        else{
            n++;
            }
        } while (d < 3100|| (1.0/n > accuracy));
    return 4.0*d/n;
    }

int main(){
    double accuracy;
    srand((int)time(0));
    std::cout << "Enter the accuracy: \n";
    std::cin >> accuracy;
    std::cout << montecarlo(accuracy) << std::endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! This is extremely helpful.

Comment: I deleted some lines in the answer’s code. They were not of any use